# Delete temporary files from geoprocessing in ArcGIS 10 and above

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, delete

I am seeing my computers C: drive fill up quite quickly. I assume its from many geoprocessing things I have done. Is there a way to find the files Arcmap creates as temporary?

The folder I am in is, C:\Users\knappk\AppData\Local\Temp\

Comment: Normally they're removed when you close ArcCatalog/ArcMap.. they should be in %tmp%\ArcXXXX where XXXX is a random hex.  look for remnants of crashed sessions in your %tmp% folder. If you have another drive change your environment settings to put %TEMP% and %TMP% environment variables on the other drive, something like D:\Temp and d:\TMP respectively that should save you C drive.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question to me. Note that as well as the temp files, ArcGIS also writes log files that can get quite large and these are not automatically cleaned up. Mine are stored to C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\History. In my case I had 7 GBs of log files accumulated over 2 years of occasional use that I was able to delete to free up space.